# Missed libraries (lidn, lldap)

Tags: libraries, make, ldap

Command `make` induces error message

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lidn
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lldap
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../bin/SomeApp] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/SomeApp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

However, `lgconfig -p | grep idn` returns

```
libidn.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11
libcidn.so.1 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.24) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcidn.so.1
libcidn.so.1 (libc6, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.24) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcidn.so.1
libcidn.so (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.24) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcidn.so
```

And `ldconfig -p | grep ldap` returns

```
libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2
libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2
```

How I can rid off this linking errors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was solved through installing dev-versions of those libraries

```
sudo apt-get install libldap2-dev
sudo apt-get install libidn11-dev
```